# Disabling automatic scrolling past end of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollview

When i reach the end of the scroll on the top div, I don't want to initiate any other scroll. I just want it to stop scrolling. Quite a reasonable request I'd say.

[**Here is a demo of the issue on JS fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TdKUz/)

Is there a way one can disable this cross browser?

As a user, you are explicitly moving you mouse to the div to interact with it. Who is the browser to assume that i now want to scroll the thing beneath it? It's surely a bug.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable overflow on the whole body when your div is focused, with something like

```
$('#scrollme').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}, function() {
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
});​
```

Modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vQSmG/

As you can see with the `top` I added, it works even if your `#scrollme` element is not at the top of the page; you don't lose the global scroll position information.

I tested in FF 3.6, IE 9 and the latest Chrome, but I don't have older IE on hands right now to make sure it works there too.

Comment: I was just trying that actually and you beat me to it. This is awesome. Thanks so much. And I'm sorry, but i think this feels better than the default browser behavior!